# Trouble with react state and shopping cart

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context, react-state, react-state-management

I have defined some react context for a shopping cart which I want to be able to access in every child component. I have also defined some methods (add to and remove from the shopping cart). I cannot get the addToCart function to work:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

const ShoppingCartContext = React.createContext();

export function useShoppingCart() {
    return useContext(ShoppingCartContext);
}

export function ShoppingCartProvider({ children }) {
    const [shoppingCart, setShoppingCart] = useState([]);

    function addToCart(item) {
        setShoppingCart(shoppingCart.concat(item));
    }

    function removeFromCart(item) {
        const index = shoppingCart.indexOf(item);
        setShoppingCart(shoppingCart.splice(index, 1));
    }

    const value = { shoppingCart, setShoppingCart, addToCart, removeFromCart };

    return (
        <ShoppingCartContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

In the file I want to access the shopping cart in, I am doing this:

```
const { shoppingCart, setShoppingCart, addToCart, removeFromCart } = useShoppingCart();
```

Then, in a useEffect(), I am doing this:

```
addToCart(["item"])
console.log(shoppingCart)
```

But it console.logs an empty array:

[image]

Comment: change to a state is asynchronous, so to see value of 'shoppingCart' use a callback function inside 'addToCart'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming that `useEffect` is called after the initial render of your child component, the following happens

```
addToCart(["item"])  // context state is [], a rerender with the new state is scheduled
console.log(shoppingCart) // context state is [], an empty array is logged
```

After this, the state updates and your child component rerenders. If you move your `console.log` out to the component body, you will see the change

```
const MyShoppingCartConsumingComponent = () => {
  const { shoppingCart, setShoppingCart, addToCart, removeFromCart } = useShoppingCart();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
     addToCart(['item'])
  }, [])

  console.log(shoppingCart)

  return <p>yo!</p>
}
```

Something like this will be logged

```
[]
['item']
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!